# UITable view cell validation for email

Tags: ios, swift

i want to validate the emailId on UItable view cell. So for this i have done:

```
   let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("QuestionWithEmailField", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? QuestionWithEmailField)!

            cell.model = model
            cell.indexPath = indexPath
            cell.TexitFieldEmail.delegate = self
            cell.lblEmail.text = model.labelText
            return cell
```

This cell is for email and there are other cells that are for phone numbers and zip codes. There are different cells for different types of fields. Now how can i validate the Emailand use **DidEndEditingTextField**.

In my QuestionWithEmailField.swift i have done this:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var lblEmail: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var TexitFieldEmail: UITextField!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
//email validations functions
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool
{
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let range = testStr.rangeOfString(emailRegEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
    let result = range != nil ? true : false
    return result
}

@IBAction func DidEndEditingTextField(sender: AnyObject) {

    let validEmailAddress = isValidEmail(TexitFieldEmail.text!)
    if validEmailAddress
    {
     print("Valid Email Address")
    }
    else{
        print("InvalidAddrss")
    }

}
```

But  i cannot validate the email for this UITextField. Now i want to validate the field after pressing the send button.how can i do this..??

Comment: 1) Could you explain why you "cannot validate the email for this UITextField"?. 2) If you want to validate after pressing send button, you need to maintain the `emailTextField` as a property and validate that textField's text. Implement that maintaining in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this: `if (cellContainEmailField) _emailTextField = cell.emailTextField`

Comment: Pressing the button?  Where?  You havet two sets of code.  Under which class are they writtein?

Comment: ok so how can i validate this.. from pressing button..??

Comment: @nynohu that emailTextField is in Xib file and how can i validate it from a loaded View controller

Comment: [I think your question is the same as this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713415/how-and-where-to-impliment-this-validation-function-in-ios-swift-3)

Comment: yes i could have done same thing if the Text field was of same view controller but it is loaded from xib

Answer (score 0):

You just need to validate inside your `TableviewCell` which contains that textfield.

You may probably notice that `didEndEditing` will not be called when you press `return` on keyboard. So you have to use `textFieldShouldReturn` from `UITextFieldDelegate` to trigger `didEndEditing`.

```
extension String {
    var isEmail: Bool {
        do {
           let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}", options: .caseInsensitive)
           return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) != nil
        }
       catch {
          return false
       }
    }
}


class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func didEndEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if sender.text!.isEmail {
            print("YES")
        } else {
            print("NO")
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: have you set "QuestionWithEmailField" as your cell's class on storyboard?

Comment: I'm doing these within storyboard not in xib btw.